# Access private youtube using objective c

Tags: objective-c, youtube, private

is there any way to access private youtube videos using objective c?

Comment: Are these videos that you may somehow have access to or just random private videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at [authentication](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication.html#Authentication) in the YouTube data API, it may be what you're looking for.